# TexLive 2020 installation Ubuntu

Tags: paths, texlive-2020

I just installed TexLive 2020 into my Ubuntu laptop following the steps written in: http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

However, when I arrive to the steps

`Post-install: setting PATH`

`After the installation finishes, you must add the directory of TeX Live binaries to your PATH—except on Windows, where the installer takes care of this. For example: PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH Use the syntax for your shell, your installation directory, and your binary platform name instead of x86_64-linux.`

I get lost. I run the command line `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` and nothing happens. I have as well TexLive 2017 installed in my laptop, but when I try with a test document, some packages like `raleway` are not installed.
I am obviously missing some steps in the PATH part. What am I suppose to do there?

Comment: You need to put the command in your `~/.profile`, or `/etc/profile`, for it to run whenever you log in. The former enables it for your user account, the latter for everyone on your box.